# How do I make an image a href from this code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this web page, here's what it looks like:

https://prnt.sc/vY4OUXrUpnr9

now I want to make the center image a link. So when they click it they are redirected to a download. Here's the current code below in index.html but I don't know what to add/how to make the image a link. I think it's something to do with href. Please let me know, but need this done.

```
<style type="text/css">
        body{
            background-color: #484848;
        }
        div.container{
                text-align: center;
                position: absolute;
                top: 45%;
                left: 42.5%;
        }
        div.container img{
            width: 70px;
        }
        div.container p{
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <img src="img/error.png">
    <p>A plugin is needed to display this content.</p>
</div>

<!-- page content end -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Edit: I would also like the words "A plugin is needed to display this content" a href link. How do I format it? Please let me know!

Comment: <a href="your link" download><img src="img/error.png"></a>

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

```
<div class="container">

    <a href="http://example.com">

        <img src="img/error.png">
        <p>A plugin is needed to display this content.</p>

    </a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="https://www.google.de">
  <img src="https://img001.prntscr.com/file/img001/UAcHefR6SIeX5mTnHUmcdg.png" width="200" height="100">
  <p>A plugin is needed to display this content.</p>
</a>
```